# The grammar of "everyone else my age"

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

> Another belief of mine: that **everyone else my age** is an adult, whereas
> I am merely in disguise.
>
> -- Margaret Atwood

Why can "else" introduce a noun phrase (my age), what part of speech is it? [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/else?q=else) doesn't seem to allow such grammar.

Or is the phrase a shortened form "everyone else at my age"? Then why "at" can be omitted?

Comment: It's short for _everyone else who is [of] my age_.

Comment: It's an example fof whiz-deletion https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info#:~:text=Whiz%2Ddeletion%20is%20a%20type,be%20from%20certain%20relative%2Dclauses.

Comment: @JavaLatte whiz-deletion only deletes who is, but why is "of" also deleted?

Comment: As @KateBunting indicated, [of] is optional in the sentence. If you were to include it, the whiz-deleted form would be "... everyone else of my age".

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes, my question is why [of] is optional in the sentence?

Comment: According to the [Cambridge Dictionary] [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of], the meaning of **of** in this kind of sentence is "that is/are", so it is it is an alternative to whiz-deletion. So you can say "Somebody who is my age" which can be whiz-deleted to "somebody my age" or you can say "somebody of my age". In the last one, **of** is syntactically a preposition and semantically "that is". You probably can say "somebody who is of my age" but it is unnecessary.

Comment: In that case, "the problem of homelessness" can be whiz-deleted to "the problem homelessness", "a rise of two percent in inflation" to "a rise two percent in inflation", 
"the skill of negotiating" to "the skill negotiating". Am I correct?

Comment: (Late reply.) No, removing "of" is not whiz-deletion; removing "who/what is/are" is whiz deletion. Sometimes "of" can be removed to give a different but still valid construction e.g. "skill of negotiating" vs "skill negotiating", "a couple of apples" vs "a couple apples", but there is no general rule which allows this in all cases. (English in some cases allows modifiers to come before or after the noun they modify, and sometimes does not require a connecting preposition.)